# .Net : main resources, tools and libraries, open source or not, to build entreprise level applications?

Tags: .net, resources, frameworks, rcp

As a young professional in .Net, I noticed that there are plenty of .Net application blocks for build an entreprise level application. Still, I could not find a place where all these resources are gathered, as an entry point to .Net development for beginners or professional.

Here is my question. Which application blocks do you use in your entreprise-level application?
Please classify your blocks (database access, GUI, testing... add tags to it dammit!), precise if it is open source or not. If your library provides functionnality in several fields (like Microsoft prism), some additional information would be great.

Be specific. No tiny useful block shall be forgotten. Vote up useful and entreprise level libraries, vote down unstable ones. Gotta catch'em all!

Of course if such a place exists, I'd be glad to get its url ;-)

Libraries :

- [Microsoft Entreprise Library](http://www.codeplex.com/entlib) (Caching, Cryptography, Data Access, Exception Handling, Logging, Policy Injection, Security, Unity ie Dependency Injection, Validation - Open Source) by Robert Harvey
- [NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/Default.aspx) (O/R Mapping, Data Access - Open Source) by g.
- [Proj.Net](http://www.codeplex.com/ProjNET) (Spatial Reference and Projection - Open Source) by George

Resources :

- [CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com/site/search?projectSearchText=&sortBy=PageViews&tagName=%2c.NET%2c&licenses=|&refinedSearch=true) (Open Source) by Nifle
- [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/) (Open Source) by Nifle
- [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/search/?type_of_search=soft&words=.net&search=Search) (Open Source) by Nifle

Comment: If you're asking people to generate a list of Open Source .Net components, you should make the question a community wiki and not a regular question. You'll be more likely to get answers that way.

Comment: By "application blocks", do you mean libraries?

Comment: @yodaj007 Yep libraries. 
@Dan Rigby. Building a wiki from scratch is slow, asking a question on SO and gathering answers is fast ;-). Maybe it does already exists, in this case it will come up pretty quickly here.

Comment: @Nelson I meant marking this question as a community wiki question. There seems to be some debate over whether certain types of questions (usually very general ones) should be marked as wiki questions from the beginning, so I was just trying to be helpful.

Comment: How do I make it a community wiki? 
+ Non open source libraries are welcomed of course.

Comment: @Nelson If you click edit on the question, there's a checkbox under the description box and to the right.

Comment: Made it a community wiki, thanks Dan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Microsoft Enterprise Library is a collection of reusable software components (application blocks) designed to assist software developers with common enterprise development cross-cutting concerns (such as logging, validation, data access, exception handling, and many others). Application blocks are a type of guidance; they are provided as source code, test cases, and documentation that can be used "as is," extended, or modified by developers to use on complex, enterprise-level line-of-business development projects.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc467894.aspx

- The Caching Application Block
- The Cryptography Application Block
- The Data Access Application Block
- The Exception Handling Application
  Block
- The Logging Application Block
- The Policy Injection Application
  Block
- The Security Application Block
- The Unity Application Block
- The Validation Application Block

Comment: Could you list the different applcation blocks provided by this library? It would help me add some tags to it. I added a link to codeplex instead. 
http://www.codeplex.com/entlib

Answer (score 1):

There are several places that have open source .Net libraries and applications for you to rummage through.

Here are a few

- [CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com/site/search?projectSearchText=&sortBy=PageViews&tagName=%2c.NET%2c&licenses=|&refinedSearch=true)
- [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/)
- [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/search/?type_of_search=soft&words=.net&search=Search)

Comment: These are resources websites, but without knowing library names, you might miss some great stuff.

Answer (score 1):

[NHibernate](https://www.hibernate.org/343.html) for persisting objects to a relational database.

Answer (score 0):

ProjNET - to deal with projections and spatial data. OpenSource!